# How to simulate JPEG compression artifacts in Compositing?

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, compression

I want to recreate something like that in my render

[image]

Comment: Hi :). What have you tried so far and where *exactly* are you stuck? :)

Comment: Didnt have much progress to be honest. I have tried adding camera grain, but the effect is quite different.

Comment: Did you try saving your render as a jpeg with very low quality settings ?

Comment: did you try pixelate filter?

Comment: If I find no other way, I ll try changing the render quality. But I would really love if I could simulate that in compositing.
And my goal is not so much about pixelating, as my render is already low res. What I really wanted to simulate are those artifacts that can be seen in the sky in the picture above.

Comment: Maybe actually save the file as actual jpeg with a *File Output* node as intermediate step, then reintroduce it as an image texture back into compositing tree.

Comment: i tried something [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/81n05ojg2qh4oi4/jpeg%20fake.blend?dl=1), separating in channels, pixelate, and a couple of chained filters, blender makes it look more complex though..! it's just an aproximation, maybe try with some images besides of render as each one needs different settings

Answer (score -1):

[image]

its a pain, and its a chore, but just use a lot of pixelate nodes. Pixelate the image by an extreme amount, then mix that with the same image pixelated by a lesser amount, and do that over several times until you reach the desired resolution. Blur nodes can be used if the compression looks too intense.

Comment: Could you show a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating some steps and final result?